# Can't passed "document" object as an argument to page.exposeFunction

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/mozilla/readability). The constructor function `Readability` requires a **document** object to be passed.

So here's the code i came up with.

```
  await page.exposeFunction('getReadability', (doc) => {
    const article = new Readability(doc).parse();
    return article;
  });
  const doc = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const article = window.getReadability(document);
    return article;
  });
```

I'm getting an error like this. Note this is just a snippet of the error message

```
  error: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
      --> starting at object with constructor 'Window'
      --- property 'parent' closes the circle
      at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
      at win.<computed> (<anonymous>:17:30)
      at <anonymous>:2:28
      at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/home/chan-dev/Coding/serverSideJs/opengraph-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:217:19)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
      at ExecutionContext.evaluate (/home/chan-dev/Coding/serverSideJs/opengraph-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:106:16)
      at _default (/home/chan-dev/Coding/serverSideJs/opengraph-scraper/helpers/link-previews.js:175:15)
      at /home/chan-dev/Coding/serverSideJs/opengraph-scraper/src/index.js:45:16,
  level: 'error',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error

```
Converting circular structure to JSON
```

means that you are trying to serialize an object with circular structure, eg:

```
var a = {};
a.b = a;
```

You are not seralizing anything explicitly, but...

As [this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5998#issuecomment-653073537) answer suggests, objects passed to puppeteer exposed functions **have to be serializable**. Unfortunately, window nor document is not serializable (`JSON.stringify(document)` will not work, probably cause document has reference to window somewhere, which has reference to itself through `parent` property). It appears that this information is missing from the docs.

If you open console and type `JSON.stringify(document)`, you'll see exactly your error, which means that under the hood puppeteer does some serialization, which is not possible for your object (document).

As an alternative, I can suggest loading page's own HTML via $.load (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp) or `document.documentElement.innerHTML` property and sending it to Readability as a string.

Comment: thanks for the response, i will try look at this approach. btw, i've just tried `JSON.stringify(document)` and it works on the console.

Comment: In the browser's console? Not possible. `JSON.stringify(document)
VM217:1 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Window'
    --- property 'parent' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6`

Comment: Yup. Idk, it works on my browser. 

Here's the result:
`{"location":{"href":"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432830/cant-passed-document-object-as-an-argument-to-page-exposefunction/63447247?noredirect=1#comment112193830_63447247","ancestorOrigins":{},"origin":"https://stackoverflow.com","protocol":"https:","host":"stackoverflow.com","hostname":"stackoverflow.com","port":"","pathname":"/questions/63432830/cant-passed-document-object-as-an-argument-to-page-exposefunction/63447247","search":"?noredirect=1","hash":"#comment112193830_63447247"},"jQuery112408479986948346796":4}`

Comment: Okay, in my case it has one more property: `google_osd_static_frame` which seems to be a handle to a Window. You might try to pass document's clone, as in Readability guide: `var documentClone = document.cloneNode(true);`, not the document itself. The clone stringifies in Chrome. But I doubt it'll do what you want...

Comment: It appears that you can get entire's page html via `document.documentElement.innerHTML` on modern browsers.

Comment: that's awesome, i'll look into that.